# Angular and karma (jasmine) : How can I find an element by class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-runner

```
beforeEach(function () {

    html = '<div class="dropdown">'+
              '<div class="trigger" >trigger</div>'+
              '<div class="dropdown">body</div>'+
           '<div>';

    inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {

        scope    = $rootScope.$new();
        element  = angular.element(html);
        compiled = $compile(element);

        compiled(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        // HERE NOT WORKING
        var trigger == element.find('div.trigger');
        var dropdown == element.find('.dropdown');

        // trigger and dropdown have both length 0

    });

    // Test doesn't pass
    it('should find the right element'), function () {
        expect(trigger.hasClass('trigger')).toBe(true);
    }

});
```

I am trying to unit test a directive, but I can't find element by class.

I would like to be able to find element with something like:

```
var trigger == element.find('div.trigger') // doesn't find anything.
```

but now I am only able to do it like this:

```
var triggers = element.find('div') // return an array of length 2.
var trigger = triggers[0];
```

How can I find an element by class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

find by class name is not supported by the AngularJS `find` function. Instead you can use vanilla javascript for this:

```
var result = element[0].querySelectorAll('.findme');
```

Now you can check if the result variable has a class of `findme` by wrapping it in an angular element.

```
angular.element(result).hasClass('findme')
```

### Fiddle

Comment: Why do you need to use hasClass on something returned by `querySelectorAll('.findme')`? It should always contain the `findme` class, shouldn't it?

Comment: Like @PetrPeller said, I don't think thats necessary. Maybe using something like `expect(result).toBeDefined()`; would make more sense.

Comment: Or using `expect(result).not.toBe(null);`

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick:
expect(element[0].querySelectorAll("div.trigger").length).not.toBe(0);